# how to bind database to crystal report?

Tags: c#, data-binding, crystal-reports, dataset

i have C# program, i have DataSet that i want to bind to crystal report.

how to do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a Typed DataSet from the "Add New Item > DataSet and give the dataset
a useful name.

In Server Explorer, drag a view with the fields you want in the report onto
the dataSet.

Create a new Crystal Report using the Wizard.

From the Report Gallery, choose "Standard" and click 'OK'

In the 'Data' tab, click the node for "More Data Sources"

Click the node for ADO .Net (XML)

Check the box for 'Use Visual Studio Data Class'

In the 'Visual Studio Data Class name' combobox, select the name of the
dataset you just created.

click 'Finish'

Choose the table displaying under the name of the dataset you just added to
the 'Data' tab and click 'Insert Table'

Format your report.