# Convertion of a LINQ stored procedure to a DataSet

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, linq, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report table which is this:

[image: Picture 1]

Now I want to make the report datasource from a Dataclass
which is this:

```
BorrowSlip1.SetDataSource(db.sp_CurrentBorrowed(TransactionID));
```

And what would happen is this:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.'
```

I always receive this error. Is there any way around this?

I have seen some tutorials but none of them show how to do it by using dataclasses context.

Is there any way I could convert the result from the stored procedure to be put in a dataset?

Thanks

Comment: Please follow the instructions outlined in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668953/how-to-bind-database-to-crystal-report

Comment: Please read the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question accordingly.